# Are storyboards forcing you to write ugly code?

Tags: iphone, ios, storyboard, segue

I've been developing everything with xib files because we needed to suport iOS4.

Now we are finally supporting only iOS5 and iOS6, so I decided to give storyboards a try, so everything is fine and easy, but I have found myself doing a lot of code like this:

```
-(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {

    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"AddPlayer"]) { //Ugly

        UINavigationController * navigationController = segue.destinationViewController;
        PlayerDetailViewController * playerDetailsViewController = [navigationController viewControllers][0]; //Super Ugly
        playerDetailsViewController.delegate = self;
    }
}
```

I don't know about you guys, but I found this code very ugly and error prone.

Is there a better way for working with Storyboards? Should I got back to xib files?

Comment: Could you explain why you say ugly? Are you referring to the comparison for the if statement?

Comment: not so ugly i think :) just unusual

Comment: I found really ugly the fact that you have to enter random strings in the storyboard and then start doing comparisons, for me is very unmaintainable, coupled and error-prone. Same goes for traversing the controllers hierarchy

Comment: Why are you doing this manually? These sorts of configuration options shod be done in the storyboard itself.

Comment: +1 I'd like to know if there's a better way to do what he's doing above. I've avoided storyboards so far but from what I've seen if you have a bunch of segues you end up with a ton of boilerplate in `prepareForSegue:sender:`. Also string comparisons for static strings is kind of gross.

Comment: @jshier I've heard a lot of people use the method above as their hook to get a reference to their controller so they can pass it data.

Comment: @jshier then teach me how to do it in the storyboard, as far as I know you can't assign custom delegates/objects in xib's/storyboards

Comment: Why not assign a constant? `#define kAddPlayerSegue @"AddPlayer"`

Comment: That will be good if you could use #defines in the storyboard

Comment: @jshier you can't assign properties/delegates on a custom view controller from the storyboard file itself...

Comment: `#define` in a storyboard? That seems like just putting a paper bag over the ugly. :-)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I worked with Storyboards quite a lot in the last app we built where I work and yeah, I agree the boilerplate code gets pretty annoying after some time, but as far as I know using `prepareForSegue` is the only way to pass parameters when using segues. 
**You can't assign properties/delegates on a custom view controller from the Storyboard itself.**

- Would I go back to using XIB's if I only target iOS 5 & 6? **It
  depends**.

If I had to build a small - medium app (not too many views and not a lot of cross-navigation between them) I would definitely use Storyboards. But when you have a lot of views and a lot of back and forth navigation between them, it really gets complicated to keep the Storyboard nice and tidy, and it feels like you are forcing yourself to use something that actually isn't the best.

On the other hand I feel Storyboards make it much easier to get a feel of the flow and general look of the app when starting from scratch, and you can even use them to create mock-ups that will actually look like the real thing.

So in essence it boils down to what your needs are when starting a project.

**EDIT:**

Another thing to take into account: if you use SVN/Git or any other VCS to work with a team, Storyboard file conflicts are a **total bitch**.

Comment: +1 for version control file conflicts with Storyboards. Did Apple not think multiple people just might have to edit a storyboard? Geez

Comment: i've had so many headaches from fixing storyboard conflicts... just to find them again in next commits

Answer (score 5):

I agree that is an ugly code and to smooth my vision I created a macro:

```
#define WhenSegueIdentifierDo(segueIdentifier, block) if([segue.identifier isEqualToString:segueIdentifier]) block();
```

And in my **prepareForSegue**:

```
WhenSegueIdentifierDo(kModalVC1ToVC2, ^
{
    //code
});

WhenSegueIdentifierDo(kModalVC1ToVC3, ^
{
    //code
});
```

I also use constants instead of hardcoded strings (although I cannot use them on storyboard) to keep it more beautiful. I also use a convention: **k** + **type of transition** + **origin view controller name** + **to** + **destination view controller name**.

You could also use

```
navigationController.topViewController
```

instead of

```
[navigationController viewControllers][0];
```

Just my 2 cents...

Comment: That block approach is actually pretty neat, But I just decided to stick with nibs/xibs. I don't like the idea of having all my views in a single file. It's very unmaintainable large teams!

Answer (score 2):

That's just the nature of the beast.   Objective-C using Cocoa conventions produces - (hopefully) self documenting, albeit, verbose code.  Looking at your example, I have no problems determining your intention.

Now, if you wanted to make it pretty, you could encapsulate all this into a macro so that it would be condensed to one line.  While it may be prettier to behold, it would certainly add unnecessary complexity in maintaing the beast.  The end user isn't going care how pretty the code is -- unless it prevents adding  new features.

As for discussing storyboards ... they are certainly different but having used them now for six months, I do  appreciate having all my nibs in one centralized place instead of spending the time to look for individual files.  It's much easier for me to find things by visual layouts, then parsing camel cased file names.  That's just me.

My advice, give them time.  In a few months if you find them inhibiting your workflow, then by all means, go back to individual nibs.  They aren't going anywhere.  At least for awhile.

Just my two cents.  Good luck!

Comment: I Agree about the product itself is what matters to the final user, but as an Engineer I have to worry for a lot more things than the just the final product.